# Make Buttons stay inline-block when toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got 3 categories acting as buttons for a toggle function. The categories are 
displayed `inline-block` and have a width of 30% each. 
When you click on one of them a paragraph appears underneath, however that causes the other two categories to be displayed underneath that paragraph. I need them to stay in one line though.
Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwj79u6j/2/) so you can see what I mean. When you click on 'Test1' the 'Test2' is moved underneath the paragraph but I need it to stay where it is.

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

**Edit**
I've got the html structure like this as it makes the layout work for mobile devices where the categories are stacked.

Answer (score 5):

I've changed your HTML structure, [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwj79u6j/6/)

HTML:

```
<div class="Categories">
  <p id="Category1">Test1</p>
  <p id="Category2">Test2</p>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.Categories p {
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

JS :

```
$('#Category1').click(function(){
  $('.moreCategory1').toggle();
});
$('#Category2').click(function(){
  $('.moreCategory2').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I should have mentioned though that I've got the current structure to make it work for mobiles where the Categories will be stacked. My bad

Answer (score 0):

This problem is easily solved by using a flex container. Not only it solves your problem, it is also easy to change for mobile in responsive web design and it is semantically correct.

HTML:

```
<div class="categories">
    <p id="Category1">Test1</p>
    <p id="Category2">Test2</p>
    <p id="Category3">Test3</p>
</div>

<div id="more1" class="moreCategory">
    <p>Content 1</p>
</div>

<div id="more2" class="moreCategory">
    <p>Content 2</p>
</div>

<div id="more3" class="moreCategory">
    <p>Content 3</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.categories {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%; /*Not necessary. Make sure its large enough to be clear*/
    flex-direction: row;
}

.categories p {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.moreCategory {
    display: none;
}
```

For Mobile:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .categories {
       flex-direction: column;
    }
    .categories p {
  width: 100%;
    }
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('#Category1').click(function() {
    if ($('#more1').is(":hidden")) $('#more1').toggle();
    if (!$('#more2').is(":hidden")) $('#more2').toggle();
    if (!$('#more3').is(":hidden")) $('#more3').toggle();
});
$('#Category2').click(function() {
    if (!$('#more1').is(":hidden")) $('#more1').toggle();
    if ($('#more2').is(":hidden")) $('#more2').toggle();
    if (!$('#more3').is(":hidden")) $('#more3').toggle();
});
$('#Category3').click(function() {
    if ($('#more1').is(":hidden")) $('#more1').toggle();
    if (!$('#more2').is(":hidden")) $('#more2').toggle();
    if (!$('#more3').is(":hidden")) $('#more3').toggle();
});
```

This should solve your problem. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpgjnbbj/1/).

**EDIT :**

If you really want the heading tabs together, but also applicable for mobile you can hide the selecting controller from my for, i.e., the topmost main div.

Hide the header tags for large screens and the same css applies. For mobiles, hide the control div and show the headers and moreContent divs without any JQuery controls. A simple if statement should do the trick(check for screen size or user agent).

Comment: Thanks but more1,more 2etc. needs to be directly under Category1, Category2 etc. on mobile